# Jar file for the mentioned import statements is required

Tags: java, common-crawl

```
import edu.cmu.lemurproject.WarcHTMLResponseRecord;
import edu.cmu.lemurproject.WarcRecord;
```

am using the import statements am getting error could you please suggest me the jar file for the above imports

Comment: IProcessWarcRecord processor = new SampleProcessWarcRecord(); still am getting error in the above syntax

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for cloud9 jar? It is available [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcloud9jar.htm).

Comment: IProcessWarcRecord processor = new SampleProcessWarcRecord(); still am getting error in the above syntax